# How can I kick a user out of a cell before using the cell contents?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am working on a google sheet script that will copy some cells and paste them somewhere else.  One of the issues I'm running into is if the user is actively editing the cell when the script is run, the script will see that cell as blank.

I've tried to make a different cell "active" or "selected" but it doesn't seem to effect the user editing the cell.

Or if I could tell if the user was editing it, and I could make them press "enter" that would work too I guess...

Thanks!

Comment: If the code sees the cell as blank when someone else is running it, then you can use that to tell if someone is editing the cell.  So, you can tell if they are editing it, from what you are describing.  You can check for a blank value `value === ""`  or `!value`.  You can also display a msg to the user with the `Browser` service.

Comment: If a user has edit access to a spreadsheet, they can edit it any time they want; a script can't hurry them up to force them to wait.

Comment: This may be of some help:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

Comment: Hmmm... Ok thanks for the input guys.  It seems like there's not a straight forward way to do this.  I was thinking I could quickly protect the cell and then unprotect it at the beginning and end of the script... but I don't think it's actually all that important - just a bug I'd like to fix.